# what is php-fpm warning “failed to acquire scoreboard”?

Tags: php, php-fpm

what is php-fpm warning "failed to acquire scoreboard" in fpm error log? **And how to fix it?**

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm.log
[08-Oct-2014 03:36:36] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:40:39] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:42:54] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
[08-Oct-2014 03:47:01] WARNING: failed to acquire scoreboard
```

use-case:

php version 5.4.25

php-fpm instance say 'pf-9000' is connecting to 2nd php-fpm instance say 'pf-9005' with fastcgi protocol on same server.
The error is visible on both php-fpm instances.

Request flow:

```
web client -> nginx -> pf-9000 -> pf-9005
```

Response flow:

```
pf-9005 -> pf-9000 -> nginx -> web client
```

Answer (score 1):

From an answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255739/what-is-php-fpm-warning-failed-to-acquire-scoreboard):

> A scoreboard is a structure that holds the state of the FPM pool and its worker threads. It's created in shared memory, and if that memory can't be allocated, an error is logged.

This answer also refers to the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_request.c#L46) where the error is thrown.

**How to fix it?**

First, give the `sysctl` a look regarding memory limits:
[How to/configure shared memory](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/How_to/configure_shared_memory)

```
sysctl -a | grep -E "shmall|shmmax"
```

or

```
ipcs -lm
```